# I am facing an error while running simple go code

Tags: rest, go, runtime, cgo

I am trying to run a simple go code

```
package main
import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
)
func homePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

}
func handleRequest() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", homePage)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil))
}

func main() {
    handleRequest()
}
```

- Go version : go1.17.5 darwin/arm64
- macOs : monterey 12.1

### Error Message:

```
# runtime/cgo
ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation.tbd' for architecture arm64
clang-10: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following commands helped me. 
 Try to reinstall Xcode command-line tools and upgrade llvm and gcc.

```
$ brew upgrade llvm
$ brew upgrade gcc
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
$ xcode-select --install
```